# How to convert List<long?> to ISet<long>

Tags: c#

There is a methods which is accepting a parameter of type `List<long?>`, I need to assign it to someTestModel ids, which are of type `ISet<long>`.

```
public void testM1(List<long?> testIds)
{
    var request = new someTestModel { ids= testIds };
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's two things we'd need here:

- a concrete type to implement `ISet<T>` - presumably `HashSet<T>` will suffice
- to change from `long?` to `long` - presumably by just ignoring any that are `null`

So, something like:

```
var hash = new HashSet<long>();
foreach(var id in testIds) {
    if(id.HasValue) hash.Add(id.Value);
}
var request = new someTestModel{ ids = hash};
```

?

Comment: Huh, and I was expecting someone would answer passing an `IEnumerable` to the constructor of the `HashSet`

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto you *could* do that, using LINQ etc, but... it would be less efficient; something like `new HashSet<long>(testIds.Where(x => x.HasValue).Select(x => x.Value))` - personally I prefer the more direct, obvious, and efficient 3-line version

Comment: And if OP prefers nulls to be included with a default value, then it could be simplified even more to `hash.Add(id.GetValueOrDefault())`